# Search SqlDatabase using different data ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Hi i can currently search the sql database using the following code, but i can only search using the Customer_firstname is there a way i can search for the surname as well as the firstname? i have found numerous tutorials and examples but all of the examples only use one datatype for the search.

```
protected void Button_cus_pmr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        //select all the data from the PMR table where it is equal to the text in the search text box
        string staSearch = "select * FROM [PMR] where (Customer_Firstname like '%" + TextBox_cus_pmr.Text.ToString() + "%)";
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = staSearch;//perform the staSearch query on the SqlDataSource1

    }
```

Comment: You should look into Store procedures or the entity framework instead of using inline sql.  They can be a security nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: @Lareau Or rather parameters, since they are a lot simpler to use for queries than stored procedures. But the fact remains that never ever use string catenation like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply add a second condition for the surname. For example:

```
string staSearch = "select * FROM [PMR] where (Customer_Firstname like '%" + TextBox_cus_pmr.Text.ToString() + "% OR Customer_Surname like '%" + TextBox_surName.Text.ToString() + "%')";
```

Replace TextBox_surName with the name of the surname text box and Customer_Surname with the name of the surname database column.

Like Lareau mentioned in a comment, this isn't a very safe way to do queries because a user could run other SQL commands on your server by entering them into the textbox. For more information on ways to avoid this, take a look at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx#paght000002_step1).

Comment: The code worked perfectly i will have a look at the article and improve the security.